# Inheriting function declaration

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17

I've built myself a template class like this

```
class BaseClass {
    public:
    class BaseClass ();

    protected:
    void TestFunction();
}
```

This "BaseClass" is now being inherited by another class in another header-file

```
#include "base.h"

class InheritingClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
    class InheritingClass ();
}
```

I'm relatively new to C++ so besides playing with the public, protected and private keywords I couldn't think of many solutions to try.

What do I have to change in this code so that my "inheritingclass.cpp" treats "TestFunction" like an declaration made in its header file?

```
#include "inheritingclass.h"

InheritingClass::TestFunction() {
...
}
```

Comment: Neither of those classes are template classes. Templates always start with the keyword `template`

Comment: The default inheritance for classes is `private`, so all the base members are private unless you add one of the other keywords.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give us a proper [mre] of the code you wonder about. The code you show isn't even valid.

Comment: Expanding on the comment by @BoP, `class InheritingClass : public BaseClass {` is probably the change you need. But the question isn't completely clear.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Save yourself 1 line of typing? LIkely not possible here.

Comment: Well yes... The original has multiple declarations with multiple arguments. It would save me a good amount of work and make my code more readable

Comment: Do you want to [override](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) your base method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for, according to me, are `virtual` functions.

The idea is that in the base class, you declare a function as `virtual` if you want it to be overridden by an inherited class:

```cpp
class BaseClass {
    public:
        BaseClass();

    protected:
        virtual void TestFunction();
}
```

The next step would be to `override` this function in your `InheritingClass.h` file:

```cpp
#include "base.h"

class InheritingClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    InheritingClass();

protected:
    void TestFunction() override;
};
```

Now in your `InheritingClass.cpp` file, you can implement this function as follows:

```
#include "InheritedClass.h"

void InheritingClass::TestFunction()
{
    // overridden implementation
}
```

Just as an extra note, make sure to declare `constructors` like this in your `header` file:

```cpp
class BaseClass
{
    public:
        BaseClass();

    ...
```

..and implement them in your `cpp` file like this:

```cpp
BaseClass::BaseClass()
{
    // constructor code
}
```

This is the proper way to declare a constructor in C++ :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) And thanks for the extra help ^^

Comment: ur welcome @user22502145 :)